# Where is wrong in this proof

Tags: fake-proofs

Suppose $a=b$.

Multiplying by $a$ on both sides gives $a^2 = ab$. Then we subtract $b^2$ on both sides, and get

$a^2-b^2 = ab-b^2$.

Obviously, $(a-b)(a+b) = b(a-b)$, so dividing by $a - b$, we find

$a+b = b$.

Now, suppose $a=b=1$. Then **$1=2$** :)

Comment: You divide by $a-b$. This is possible and justified only if $a-b\ne0$. So the proof would be wrong in general because you *might* have $a-b=0$ unless you proof otherwise (or treat the case specially). In this particular case, you *assume* right away that $a=b$, hence $a-b=0$.

Comment: I would be amazed if this wasn't a duplicate, but I can't find a version of this question because I'm not sure what keywords to search for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mistake is that from the fact that $$xy = zy$$ you cannot conclude that $x=z$. You can only conclude that $x=z$, if $y \neq 0$, i.e.,
$$xy = zy \implies x=z \color{red}{\text{ or } y=0}$$

---

In your case, you had $$(a-b)(a+b) = b(a-b)$$
Since $a = b$, we have $a-b = 0$ and hence you cannot cancel $a-b$ from both sides, i.e.,
from the fact that
$$(a-b)(a+b) = b(a-b)$$
we can only conclude that
$$a+b = b  \color{red}{\text{ or } a-b=0}$$
The $\color{red}{\text{later}}$ is what is valid in your case, since you started with the assumption $a=b$, i.e., $a-b=0$.

Comment: yes.that's right

Answer (score 0):

By a simple example:

if( A = 0 ) A * 5 = A * 7 and by dividing by A we have 5 = 7.

Then we can dividing by A if A not equal to zero.

Comment: by omit this fact we can proof any of the number is equal to any of the other number